# get emails from specific emails - instantly

Tags: notifications, gmail, email, push-notifications

I'm trying to make sure that when I get specific emails, I get notified instantly, loudly, and even if I'm in "do not disturb".

The emails are going into a gmail account. These are things I've done so far:

- Set up a new email, log into that email on the Samsung "Email" app, turn notifications on for that email app, create a filter on the original email that forwards to this email.
- Create a filter on the original email with a label, go into the "gmail" app filter notification settings, allow syncing on the filter with notifications.

both these methods work to get notifications on my filter... but both of them seem to be delayed about 15 minutes (I assume the filter and send and perhaps the "email" app make up that 15 minutes on the first option... and the filter and syncing within the phone make up the 15  minutes on the second option).

Comment: Have you disabled battery saving for the app? Also make sure that the app and the mail server uses IMAP IDLE otherwise the app has to check periodically for new mails which causes a delay and additionally will cost you a lot battery.

Comment: i set gmail app to "unrestricted" for battery.. and indeed got the notification very quickly using my label filter notification... will have to see how much this drains the battery.. i don't see anything about imap idle